# Ignoring errors in makemigrations that can be silenced by in system check, Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.0

Using [a version](https://github.com/datamade/django-proxy-overrides/pull/1) of [django-proxy-overrides](https://schinckel.net/2015/05/13/django-proxy-model-relations/), I'm overriding a field in a Proxy model that appears a the base model. I'm using Django 2.0

This would cause Django's system check framework to complain, but in my settings file I have set:

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ["fields.E305", "fields.E304", "models.E006",
                          "models.E017"]
```

so `python manage.py runserver` works fine (and the overriding works beautifully).

However, when I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, Django raises an exception complaining about the clash in names:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'person' in class 'ProxyBillSponsorship' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'BillSponsorship'.
```

Is there anyway around this? I have tried setting

```
class Meta:
    managed=False
```

on the the proxied models in the hope that `makemigrations` would ignore these models, but no luck.